# Concatenate over dimension in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have for `x`

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]]

 [[ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]] # shape (2,2,3)
```

I want

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]] # shape (2,6)
```

That is to say, I want to concatenate all the items in the middle dimension.

I can get this result in this particular case with

```
x.reshape(2, 2*3)
```

Or more abstractly

```
x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*x.shape[2])
```

Is there a compact, numpythonic way to get this result for arbitrary-dimension `x`, preferably without having to do any index arithmetic myself?

I've been playing with the `concatenate` function to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about the size of the first dimension, you could use

```
x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
```

The `-1` means the size of that dimension will be determined implicitly. This will also work for higher dimensional arrays, provided that there is not more than one `-1` in the tuple of new dimensions.

You can also do this with a direct assignment to the `shape` attribute of your array:

```
x.shape = (x.shape[0], -1)
```

The main difference between using `x.reshape(...)` and directly assigning to `x.shape` is that whilst the former might create a copy if it isn't possible to change the shape of `x` without also modifying the underlying memory buffer (e.g. if `x` is non-contiguous), the latter will never generate a copy and will raise an `AttributeError` instead.